# How to get an object of multiple array using Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array, rename, file-rename

I have 2 array. I want to mapping the array then get the object of the array and use it for rename a file.
I tried this. But the file name is not correct as the object of the array it suppose to be.

This is the xml format that I get some information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assign>
     <define>
          <systemid value="8537">
          <description crm="AE/PR" priority="0"/>
          <description crm="S1/W1/W2/ZH" priority="2"/>
          <description crm="AP" priority="3"/>
          </systemid>
     </define>
</assign>

$CRMs = @("AE", "S1", "AP")

     foreach ($c in $CRMs)
     {      
          $priority = $JobSequence.jobassignseq.userdefineseq.systemid | Where-Object {$_.value -like "*$SSID*"} |
          Select-Object -ExpandProperty description | Where-Object {$_.crm -like "*$c*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty priority
          Write-Host "Prio $priority"

          
          $check = $JobSequence.jobassignseq.userdefineseq.systemid | 
          Where-Object {$_.value -like "*$SSID*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty description | 
          Select-Object priority, crm | Where-Object {$_.priority -eq "$priority"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty crm

          $C1 = $check | ForEach-Object {$_ -split "/"}
          Write-Host "CRM: $C1"
          
          $Job = (Get-ChildItem $PathOp\$Image\*.job)
          $C1 | ForEach-Object {
               for ($i = 0; $i -lt $C1.count;  $i++) {    
                    
                    $Job[$i] | Rename-Item -NewName {("$priority")[$i] + "`_$Date`_" + $_.Name.Replace('.job','.que')}
               }  

          }      
     }
```

My Expectatioin is the the priority `0` should be assign to a file with crm AE or PR, priority 2 should be assign to file with crm S1 or W1 or W2 or ZH, and priority 3 should be assign to file with crm AP.

Anyone can help me please, really appreciated. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a bit of extraneous code that you either need to include how it comes into play or exclude it. One recommendation is to use the benefits of XML to get the information you're after. Hopefully this example can lead you in the right direction.

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assign>
     <define>
          <systemid value="8537">
          <description crm="AE/PR" priority="0"/>
          <description crm="S1/W1/W2/ZH" priority="2"/>
          <description crm="AP" priority="3"/>
          </systemid>
     </define>
</assign>
'@

$description = $xml.SelectNodes("//description")
```

`$description` now contains all 3 nodes

```
crm         priority
---         --------
AE/PR       0       
S1/W1/W2/ZH 2       
AP          3 

$CRMs = "AE", "S1", "AP"

foreach($c in $CRMs)
{
    "Priority for CRM {0} is {1}" -f $c,
        ($description | where crm -match $c | select -ExpandProperty priority)
}
```

A couple of things to note.

For readability I put the second string passed to the string format expression on the next line, since commas are natural line breaks.

The @() around your list is not needed, it will already be an array.

```
$CRMs = "AE", "S1", "AP"

$CRMs.GetType().basetype.name

Array
```

Comment: hi  @Doug Maurer thank you for your advice. really appreciated. 
but my expectation I can rename the file in the `$Job` consider to priority and crm.
if you don't mind, could you please help me to give advice on it? Thank you